# How to color code/highlight values exceeding a specific amount?

Tags: html

I'm currently running a .sh script that basically pulls values from a .txt file and displays them in a table using HTML.

I've been given a requirement where I need to color code the values if they exceed a certain amount.

I'm not really sure how to proceed with this as I'm pretty sure I can't pull this off using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shell script to pull values from a .txt file and display them in a table using HTML, then you can use the `test` command in the script to add a conditional statement that will insert the code to color-code the value.

I assume that your shell script generates a HTML file after reading the .txt file. You can use conditional statement to surround the value with the font tag.

```
THRESHOLD=420
if [ $val -gt $THRESHOLD ]; then
    echo "<font color=\"#ff0000\">$val</font>"
else
    echo $val
fi
```

where $val is the value that is to be color-coded.

Comment: Great, that did the job. Just one small hiccup, if my $val is let's say -2000 and my $threshold value is 1000 it still seems to be passing the if condition.

Comment: Doesn't seem right. That should not pass the if condition and instead trigger the else condition. Could you provide the code perhaps ?

Comment: This is the condition I have implemented right now: 

if [ $DPI_VOLZ_Echo_3 > 1 ]; then
echo "<font size="2" face="arial" color="black">" >> CheckMail
 echo "<tr align="center"><td>$DPI_DATE_Echo_3</td>
 <td align="left"> $DPI_SUBS_Echo_3</td>
 <td>$CBS_SUBS_Echo_3</td>
 <td>$DPI_VOL_Echo_3</td>
 <td><font color = \"#ff0000\">$DPI_VOLZ_Echo_3</font></td>" >> CheckMail
 echo "</font>">>CheckMail
else....... same condition as above but without the red
fi

Comment: Is negative value of DPI_VOLZ_Echo_3 passing the if condition ?

Comment: No, e.g I have dpi_Volz_echo_3 as -0.12 it is still highlighting the variable as red in html. The only time I've gotten the condition to pass if I used $DPI_VOLZ_Echo_3 = 1, in that case the condition passes perfectly.

Comment: The condition looks fine, your problem should not occur. You could have messed up some tags maybe ?